# Google Analytics - Understanding and Dissecting the Snippet: What is | | [ ];

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So I'm an analyst and, while my job does not require I know Javascript it'd sure help. I'd like to understand fuller the Google Analytics snippet.

I'm looking at a Google Analytics Snippet:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'example.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

According to W3 Schools gaq is an object, in this instance it appears to be an array. The first value in the array is gaq.push set account. Fine.

But what are the "|| [ ];" on the first line?

Answer (score 2):

It means that if `_gaq` is `undefined` then set it to be an empty array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the double bar || means "empty"? Good to know.

Comment: No, they mean _or_ – so the result of that expression is either `_gaq`, if such a variable already exists and does not have a value that evaluates to false, _or_ a new empty array.